# What do you get when you complete bonus objectives (with the blue plus on it)?

Tags: borderlands-2

Some missions / quests have a bonus task to complete. What are the advantages to completing this task before handing in my quest? Better loot? More money? Anything else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Completing bonus objectives contributes to the Compl33tionist challenge, which in turn gives you badass ranks.

There are five levels to this challenge, similar to most other challenges:

```
    Level       Badass ranks gained
---------------------------------------
    Level 1     10  
    Level 2     25
    Level 3     45  
    Level 4     70  
    Level 5     100
```

Comment: Does this mean that the extra objectives have no impact on the quest reward?

Comment: That's not what I am saying. It is possible, but no one has been able to confirm this. There doesn't seem to be extra loot involved. There might be extra xp or money, but again no one has confirmed it. I am not putting this in my answer something that is purely speculation.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to clarify whether you were saying the other wasn't the case by omission.

Comment: +1 @JamesJiao but perhaps for a full answer (a confirmation of extra xp or money, etc) - maybe this question is bounty worthy?

Answer (score 8):

I can say with certainty that completing bonus objectives adds to the cash reward, and was true for each quest i tested.

If you look at the quest menu before completing a bonus objective, take note of the stated cash reward, then go and complete one (or more) bonus objectives.  Now return to the quest menu and the new, increased dollar reward amount should have changed.

As far as I've been able to tell, this (along with the “completionist” challenge, and sometimes a bit more dialogue) appears to be the only benefit of completing the bonus objectives.  I have never seen any direct experience point increase, or any kind of correlation to the stats of quest reward items.  The only other possible benefit may be an increase in drop rates for quest related enemies, but thats just total speculation, and I have not noticed any significant change (and with BL2's drop rates, testing this would be very difficult, and would require literal thousands of test runs).

Comment: I think it tells you about the cash reward bit on the first story mission with a bonus objective

Answer (score 8):

The 'Dwarven Allies' mission in the 'Tiny Tina's Assault on Dragon Keep' DLC seems to be different from the other cases. Completing the bonus objective (Punch ancient dwarven puzzle) will make you miss a loot reward and access to a locked dice loot chest.

[image: Dwarven Allies - 'Punch ancient dwarven puzzle' bonus objective]

Answer (score 2):

In the case of the Mission Assassinate the Assassins the rewards went from 10900XP to 10900XP+1330$ per objective. (TVHM)