# Is there any bonuses to complete optional quests?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do you get when you complete bonus objectives (with the blue plus on it)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89337/what-do-you-get-when-you-complete-bonus-objectives-with-the-blue-plus-on-it)

Sometimes you'll find a mission like "Assassinate the Assassins", where optional missions are presented.

In the mission aforementioned, it will ask you to murder certain assassins via a certain damage type, like pistols, shotguns, or melee.

Do these optional requirements add anything to the mission reward?  Or are they there for nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if they add anything to the mission proper, but apart from adding a little challenge (and self-satisfaction), you also get badass ranks for completing a certain number of them.

Answer (score 1):

No, mission reward does not change.

The only thing you gain is score towards a Badass Challenge -> Badass Ranks.